# How to add commas in number pages in pagination MUI?

Tags: material-ui, pagination

I have a pagination with MUI [image]

I want to add commas in number pages, for example: `39,233`

Answer (score 0):

I solved building a custom pagination using `usePagination`, more information here https://mui.com/material-ui/react-pagination/#usepagination

Comment: Having trouble finding a good answer for this question.  Can you provide a snippet of what you got working?  Thanks!